# Sample t-test in Matlab

Tags: matlab, t-test

In Matlab I have to generate two Gaussian random samples with distributions:

1. `N(100,5)`
2. `N(115,15)`

Then run the simulation 1,000 times and compute how many times the null hypothesis was rejected out of 1,000 times for each sample sizes scanning from 2 to 50.

Finally, I need to plot the result of the rejections of `H0` against the sample size.

```
h = zeros(1000,1);
k = 0;

for i = 1:1000
    r1 = ();
    r2 = ();
    for j= 2:50
        r1(j-1)=normrnd(100,5,[1,j]);
        r2(j-1)=normrnd(110,15,[1,j]);
    end
    h(i)=ttest2(r1,r2)
    if h(i)==1
        k=k+1;
    end
    percent_of_rejection_Null=(k/1000*100);
end
%plot(h vs sample_size)
```

Could somebody help me to correct the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a few issues with your code:

1. `ri` is a vector of changing size so you need to append it to a struct that can store elements with different sizes -> cell array.
2. `percent_of_rejection_Null` needs to be a vector to store all the values.
3. you didn't specify what type of plot you are looking for specifically, I showed the bar plot but it's easy to adjust to the desired one you need.
4. the calculation of `h` was problematic, its a vector of 50 each iteration thus need to calculate the sum of `1`.

The piece of code is:

```
h = zeros(1000,1);
percent_of_rejection_Null = zeros(1000,1);
k = 0;

for i = 1:1000
    r1 = {};
    r2 = {};
    for j= 2:50
        r1{j-1}=normrnd(100,5,[1,j]);
        r2{j-1}=normrnd(110,15,[1,j]);
    end
    h = cellfun(@ttest2, r1, r2);
    k = sum(h==1);
    percent_of_rejection_Null(i) = (k/1000*100);
end
figure;
plot(percent_of_rejection_Null)
```

The resulted plot is:

[image]

If the output isn't what you were after, please edit your question in order for me to adjust.

Comment: Clear now! Thank you

Comment: You can simplify the code by calling `ttest2` within the same loop in which you make the random samples. Then you don’t need to store the intermediate data, you just accumulate the count in `k`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo you absolutely right, but I wanted to keep the same logic as possible to be able to point out the flaws of the code. the use of `ri` is indeed unnecessary unless one uses it outside of the loop and it wasn't mentioned

Comment: @DavidS I still have some doubts whether my original code is correct, though. Eventually, I want to plot the number of rejections vs. the sample sizes scanning from 2 to 50. Therefore, the doubt I have is whether I should use simply `r1(j-1)=normrnd(100,5)` instead of `r1(j-1)=normrnd(100,5,[1,j])` because otherwise for every simulation my simulated samples will always be of the same size. What do you think?

Comment: @FunnyBuzer I don't know what is your aim in the code you gave us, the doubt you have might be true to keep the vector sizes identical but it might not. You need to think of your problem and come to the conclusion if the different sizes is important or not with respect of the problem you try to solve; Hope it makes more sense